# permissionhandler package is throwing an error

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I tried to add
 to AndroidManifest.xml
But the package is throwing multiple errors

e.g.
error: cannot find symbol
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
symbol:   variable S
location: class VERSION_CODES

error: cannot find symbol
case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN:
symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
location: class permission

the above error message repeats itself for BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT

I don't know what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you set compileSdkVersion in your android/app/build.gradle file to 31

Reference : [Flutter Github Issue Link](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/712)

Answer (score 0):

Build.VERSION_CODES.S is the last update of android sdk, please check if exist update

Answer (score 0):

go to `android/app/build.gradle`
change `compileSdkVersion` to 31 then do a `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

changing the compileSdkVersion to 31 in your android\app\build.gradle can fix this issue